# Read cookie from a different port using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, http, dom, cookies

Is it possible to read using JavaScript or TypeScript a cookie set by localhost:3000 on an angular app running on localhost:4200

Whenever I see `document.cookie` from my angular code all I see are the localhost:4200 cookies, not the cookies sent by the development server, though cookies are supposed to be port-agnostic.

EDIT: I ended up using the angular proxy to redirect the requests to my development server.

Comment: No that's not possible. The host must be identical, that's down to the protocol, domain and port of the request.

Comment: you cannot access another domains cookie from your site, you would have to use a chrome extension.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that cookies are supposed to be port-agnostic? Cookies are sensitive to origin, which includes the scheme, domain, and port.

Comment: Yes, you can set cookies from different port. You just have to set `withCredentials: true` when sending a request. Show how do you send the request

Comment: I need to implement a cookie-to-header csrf scheme. So withCredentials won't work, because that would only add a Cookie header and I need to add a X-XSRF-TOKEN header with the cookie value. I ended up using angular proxy to serve all cookies from the same origin. Thanks everyone!